# My Dell laptop halts after 1 hour of use n switches to a black screen on shutting down

Tags: windows-7

My Dell laptop with windows 7 just halts after about 1 hour of use with its cursor still working, and when I press the turn-off button it switches to a black screen.

Ctrl+alt+del doesn't work. I have to remove the battery for few seconds to get another 1 hour of use.

How can I find the cause of the problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest versions of all your drivers.

Comment: Black screen? Is the screen ON but showing black? or is the screen off? or is the background black? or does it completely turn off? I don't understand how removing the battery is helping, are you turning it off that way?

Comment: Are you actively using the laptop? That may just be display sleep...

Comment: yeah ma laptop helds after 1 hour of use with its cursor still movng..have tried ctrl+alt+del bt didnt work...thn on shuttng it down it's screen turns black but still working...at last i hav to remov the battery

Comment: screen is on just showing black...no it doesnt completly turn off...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities for this.  To diagnose/fix, try some of the following:

1)Download and install the latest driver set from Dell - include the Chipset and Graphics drivers.

2)Try a system restore to a date when you know this was working.

3)Set your laptop power options to not disable your screen

4)Disable screen savers

5)Check windows error logs for a faultering service or process.

Hoep one of these points you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Check if the windows is activated. more info here

> Unlike Windows XP and Vista, failure to activate Windows 7 leaves you with an annoying, >but somewhat usable system. According to a Microsoft developer blog post on "Microsoft Developer Network," if you don't choose to activate Windows 7 during installation, you will see an "Activate Windows Online Now" message in the system tray. If you don't activate then, you will see and "Activate Now" message every day from day four through day 27. Until day 30, you will get the "Activate Now" message every four hours until day 30. After day 30, you will get the "Activate Now" message every hour, along with a notice that your Windows version is not genuine whenever you launch the Control Panel. In addition, Windows 7 does not perform any system updates after the grace period. Finally, Windows will automatically turn your screen background image to black every hour – even after you change it back to your preference. This behavior continues until you successfully activate Windows 7. More info here [What Happens If Windows Is Not Activated?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/happens-windows-not-activated-34196.html)

To confirm activation press

```
Windows Key+R
```

then type

```
slui.exe
```

[image: windows run prompt]

if Windows & is activated you should get a window like this

[image: Activated windows]

if not, contact Microsoft or manufacturer to activate windows

Comment: when i start my pc in safemode it works normal.....i think it is a windows issue

Comment: try Booting into safe mode and removing the display driver p/s make sure you delete the driver. The download a new copy of the driver and reinstall.